# Manhwa where the female lead transmigrates into the body of the wife of one of the brothers of the original female lead, and wants a divorce

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

The story is about a girl who wakes up in a novel as a side character who is meant to marry one of the brothers of the original female lead (OGFL).

She at first was okay with that idea, as this novel was her favorite, and thought that it would be cute to see closely how her husband's brother-in-law and father-in-law would dote on the OGFL. It turns out that they completely ignored her existence; the brother would always follow her sister and ignore our female lead (FL) completely, and he wouldn't care at all about her.

When choosing a wedding dress, the OGFL started to try on the wedding dresses, and the family forgot and ignored the FL; when she finished, the brother selected the dress that the OGFL tried and ignored everything that the FL tried. When the FL got tired of the family, she wanted a divorce, but they wouldn't accept that because she didn't want to lend them the mine property that she had. The OGFL would try to convince her not to divorce and give them the mine, which she didn't accept. The FL, in her process of divorce, meets a guy who is an illegitimate son of the emperor.

The OGFL has blue long hair in two ponytails and she reincarnated, which is the reason that she knew about future events because she would read everything in newspaper. The brother who is married has blonde hair.

Comment: Hi. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Answer (score 1):

This is *[I Will Divorce the Female Lead's Siscon Brother](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-will-divorce-the-female-leads-siscon-brother)*.

> "We're getting a divorce." Ethel, who reincarnated into her favorite novel, has married the female lead's brother Liena. She thought her marriage life was genuine, but soon enough she became tired of a husband who cared only for his sister and whose attention was always centered on Liena, yet was cold to her, so she filed for divorce.

The protagonist reincarnates in a book world; the story opens with her already married to her husband. The OGFL, the husband's sister, matches your description - light blue hair tied up in twintails. The husband is also blonde.

[image]

Everyone in the family excessively dotes on the sister.

[image]

The wedding dress scene is in chapter 2 and goes pretty much as described. It's a flashback to before their wedding; the protagonist is trying on multiple dresses and showing them to her husband, who ignores her and declares that everything looks good.

Then the sister comes in, tries on several dresses, and the husband and the rest of the family all shower her with attention. The husband picks out a dress that the sister wore and the protagonist never tried on; back in the present the husband tries comforting his angry wife by referencing the dress she looked so good in. Except she never wore it.